# Row-wise concatenation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, concatenation

How can I concat strings in a pandas Dataframe row-wise and create a new row out of it?

[image]

Here for example, I want to create a new row by concatenating the values in all cells of index 3 and 4.

So the desired row would look like this:

```
pd.Series([Brand Model, RIVIAN RIT, LUCID Air Drean Edition])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right you can use list-comprehension with `str.join` for the task:

```py
out = [" ".join(df[c]) for c in df]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
['Brand Model', 'RIVIAN R1T', 'LUCID Air Dream Edition']
```

---

DataFrame used:

```
        Col1    Col2               Col3
Index                                  
3      Brand  RIVIAN              LUCID
4      Model     R1T  Air Dream Edition
```

---

EDIT: To append the row:

```py
df.loc[df.index.max() + 1] = [" ".join(df[c]) for c in df]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
              Col1        Col2                     Col3
Index                                                  
3            Brand      RIVIAN                    LUCID
4            Model         R1T        Air Dream Edition
5      Brand Model  RIVIAN R1T  LUCID Air Dream Edition
```

Comment: Actually I want to add a new row to the dataframe itself instead of creating a separate list